# How to model table hierarchy

Tags: sql, database-design, architecture, hierarchy

I'm trying to make an application about formula 1. I have three tables: Team, Driver, And Race Results. I'm thinking about three options (and maybe I'm missing more):

Have a derived table Driver_Team. Have a Driver_TeamId in that table. Use that Driver_TeamId in the Race Results table. This seems to solve most of the queries I think I am going to use, but feels awkward and I haven't seen it anywhere.

Have Driver.DriverId and Team.TeamId in the Race Results table. This has the problem of not being able to add extra information. I don't know yet what information, maybe the date of the start of joining a new team. Then I would need a junction table (because that information is not Race Result related).

The last one: Have a junction table Driver_Team, but have only the Driver.DriverId as Foreign Key in the Race Results table. Problem is, queries like "How much points did team x get in season y/several seasons" really really horrible.

Am I missing another solution? If yes, please tell me! :-) Otherwise, which of these solutions seems the best?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first option gets my vote. I'd also suggest adding a Race table (to hold data such as track, date, conditions, etc.), and make Race_Results the combination of Driver_Team and Race.

[image]

Comment: Yes, someone else suggested as well to add a Race table, and I completely agree. It's in! I've drawn it out and it makes a lot of sense, having a junction table for the three tables Race, Team and Driver.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

RaceResult - Driver - DriverTeam - Team

Where RaceResult contains `race_date`, DriverTeam contains ( `driver_id`, `team_id`, `team_join_date` and `team_leave_date` ). Then you would be able to get all the info you're asking about in your question, even though the queries may be complicated.

Comment: So, the Race Results table contains only the race_date? Or did you mean that that table also get's driver_id and team_id?

Comment: You should accept Joe Stefanelli's answer. Even though my idea with dates is good, his quick-n-dirty solution will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Just brainstorming, one object model may look like this. Note the conspicuous lack of an "id" field on RaceResult, as the finishing position acts perfectly as a natural key (one driver per finishing position). Of course, there may be lots of other options as well.

```
Team:
  id
  name

Driver:
  id
  name
  team_id

Race:
  id
  venue
  date

RaceResults:
  position
  driver_id
  race_id
```

Comment: Interesting with the use of the Race table. It makes sense to have one of those of course. But wouldn't you still have to write a pretty long query for looking How much points a team x got in season y/several seasons? Because a team can have up to four drivers in a season, so the query would contain at least an IN and some date comparisons...

Answer (score 0):

For the kind of queries you're talking about, I think DriverId and TeamId should both be in RaceResults. If you want to store additional information about an association between a driver and a team, then that should be placed in a separate table. This appears to create a little bit of redundancy, since the driver/team pair in the race table will be limited by the employment dates in the DriverTeam table, but given the complexities of contracts and schedules, I think it may end up being not especially redundant.

I like the way you are planning the DB to support your queries. I have run into way too much OOP thinking in DB design over the years!

Comment: Thank you, for as well as your answer as your compliment. I usually try the approach to think about the entities as well as the queries I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you only store DriverId and TeamId in the RaceResults table, then you cannot associate a driver to a team without a RaceResult.